# mrtg show average when counter data missing

Tags: mqtt, cacti, mrtg

I'm graphing my power meter with an old laptop in my barn.
This sends data using mqtt to mrtg(cacti)

Lately this laptop has begun to lockup when playing spotify.
This is a separate issue.

However, when I reboot, all the power used in the mean time is shown as being used in a single time period, giving a huge spike, so the rest of the data is hardly visible.

Is it possible to, when the data finally arrives, to intrapolate it on all the missing datapoints?

[image: Graph of power usage]

The laptop sending data was down between Sat 18:00 and Sun 11:00 approx, but of cause the real powermeter keeps running.

I'd rather have a straight line between the two datapoints, it is still loss of data, but is more true than a spike.

---

Edit: Complication, as Cacti reads the data asynchroneously from mqtt, it keeps getting the latest count even if the data is stale.

I guess I need to get my mqtt->cacti interface to send NaN or U if the timestamp of the data has not changed.

Comment: Just limiting the max-value is not good enough, then the used power will be missed in the aggregate daily/weekly/monthly/yearly graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Add a timestamp to the message that way you can rebuild the data as the queued messages are delivered when the laptop reconnects to the broker.
2. Use a QOS 0 subscriptions and ensure that clean session is set to true, this will mean the missing readings are dropped. Zero data is probably easier to interpret from the graph than a large spike.